# How to convert string variable to KeyEvent - General approach

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java and I have one question that is bugging me for days.

I am building small app where you press certain key on keyboard and then it does something. Generally - it will play drums

Here's the example.

```
private void KeyListener(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)         

switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_Q: new AePlayWave("kits/acoustic/Bass.wav").start();;
         break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_W: new AePlayWave("kits/acoustic/Bass.wav").start();;
         break; 
}
```

This is clear. You press Q button and then you get the bass drum kick . I just copied the part of the code, there are more elements like snare, cymbals, etc.

I have built the `CONFIGURE KEYS` option which takes Strings and passes them to combo boxes. I have created combo boxes with all letters on keyboard so the user can change the layout if default is not working for him/her.

I have a public class with a variable:

```
Public static SnareKey1 = "Q";
```

When you change the combo box then `SnareKey1` is changed to let''s say - `Y` (or whatever). That works BUT ----

My question is: How can I transfer this `SnareKey1` to `KeyEvent`. Am I doing this with correct approach or I need a different one?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar%28int%29

Comment: Did you add your keyListener to the combo box button that you are pressing and implemented KeyPressed event?

Comment: Start by taking a look at the Key Bindings API, [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it will be eaiser to change the assocation of the given `Action` and the key as they are logically separated...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this!

You just can't use variables in CASE (switch statement). You need constant expression.

I have resolved this with IF/ELSE statement.

Basically, I added KeyListener to the main form and wrote IF evt.keycode = snareKey.hashcode then play the sound.